# A Django library for Gmail

Tags: python, django, gmail, gmail-imap

I'm looking for an API or library that gives me access to all features of Gmail from a Django web application.

I know I can receive and send email using IMAP or POP3. However, what I'm looking for are all the GMail features such as marking emails with star or important marker, adding or removing tags, etc.

I know there is a Settings API that allows me to create or delete labels and filters, but I haven't found anything that actually allows me to set labels to emails, or set emails as starred, and so on.

Can anyone give me a pointer?

Comment: something like [Access to Gmail labels](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_gmail_labels_x-gm-labels)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google provides [GMail APIs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/). Note in particular the [IMAP Extensions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/#imap_extensions) section of the previous linked documentation, in particular [Access to Gmail labels: X-GM-LABELS](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_gmail_labels_x-gm-labels) *(thanks for the more detailed pointer @Mr.Steak)*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look at context.io, I've used it before and it works great.